# showDialog in Activity not displaying dialog

Tags: java, android, dialog, showdialog

Here is my code:

```
public class TasksList extends ListActivity {
    ...
    private static final int COLUMNS_DIALOG = 7;
    private static final int ORDER_DIALOG = 8;
    private Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    ...
     /**
     * @see android.app.Activity#onCreateDialog(int)
     */
    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        Dialog dialog;
        final String[] columns;
        Cursor c = managedQuery(Tasks.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        columns = c.getColumnNames();
        final String[] order = { "Ascending", "Descending" };

        switch (id) {
        case COLUMNS_DIALOG:
            AlertDialog.Builder columnDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            columnDialog.setSingleChoiceItems(columns, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    bundle.putString("column", columns[which]);
                }
            });
            dialog = columnDialog.create();
            break;
        case ORDER_DIALOG:
            AlertDialog.Builder orderDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            orderDialog.setSingleChoiceItems(order, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    String orderS;
                    if (order[which].equalsIgnoreCase("Ascending"))
                        orderS = "ASC";
                     else
                        orderS = "DESC";

                    bundle.putString("order", orderS);
                }
            });
             dialog = orderDialog.create();
             break;
        default:
            dialog = null;
            break;
        }

        return dialog;
    }
    /**
     * @see android.app.Activity#onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem)
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case SORT_MENU:
            showDialog(COLUMNS_DIALOG);
            showDialog(ORDER_DIALOG);
            String orderBy = bundle.getString("column") + bundle.getString("order");

            Cursor tasks = managedQuery(Tasks.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, orderBy);
            adapter = new TasksAdapter(this, tasks);
            getListView().setAdapter(adapter);

            break;
        case FILTER_MENU:
            break;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

The `showDialog` doesn't display the dialog. I used the Debugger and it does executes these statements, but the dialog doesn't show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not breakaing from your switch statements in onCreateDialog. Are you just setting it null every time?

Comment: I just fixed that, but I get still get a "NullPointerException" at "String orderBy = bundle.getString("column") + bundle.getString("order");"

Comment: Well, if you "still" get an NPE, you should have mentioned you got an NPE in the first place. Where do you define `bundle`? I just see it being used.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include that. The exception still occurred.

Comment: I did. It's the line that starts with "private Bundle bundle"

Comment: That's the declaration, not the definition. If that's all there is, why do you expect that to be anything other than null?

Comment: The dialogs still don't show. Through the debugger, the steps are executed, but the dialogs are not displayed. It just skips to String whose content is "nullnull".

Comment: Showing a dialog is asynchronous. The lines You can't expect your bundle to be filled right after you call `showDialog`

Comment: When you debug or when you run it normally? It's probably not showing because you're crashing with an NPE before the dialog ever shows

Comment: In both cases. The NPE isn't the problem anymore, that's fixed.

Comment: So what happens instead? I don't see how you can get past that piece of code where you expect the bundles to be full

Comment: Instead I get: "ERROR/AndroidRuntime(939): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: nullnull: , while compiling: SELECT _id, title, completed FROM tasks ORDER BY nullnull". That's because the dialog box doesn't allow the user to decide what to order by (and fill the bundles).

Comment: No, it's because you're trying to use results of the user's interaction with the dialog before android can even draw the dialog boxes. Like I said, showing the dialog box is asynchronous. You CANNOT use the values like you are using. Period.